# How to make liquid layout in css using em?

Tags: css

Does using `em` as css unit solve the problem in difference in monitor resolution (800x600 vs. 1024x768)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `em` sets the css targets size relative to the pre-calculated `em block` of the parent. See [wikipedia for more info on what an Em is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)).

Basically, as the resolution goes up, the computed size of an Em goes up to. The size of the Em block is a function of the resolution, and the users-preference (font-size) -- so you get the best of both worlds.

This is why W3C suggests using Em for fluid displays.

Comment: “The size of the Em block is a function of the resolution, and the users-preference (font-size)” — really? I thought it was just a function of the font-size. How does resolution affect it?

Comment: No, afaik, the Em block *is* the font-size. However, it isn't such that it is set to a constant in pixels; instead, it is a function of resolution/dpi and user-agent-settings.. I could be wrong, it could be a function of dpi+user-agent where DPI is a function of resolution or statically set. I'm not a font guy, and I think many of these points extend outside of the question. Enlighten me if I'm wrong though, and I'll withdraw the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If by "solving the problem in difference in monitor resolution" you mean making it scale like a vector image, then no. An em is a unit of measurement that scales depending on the font size the user has selected (for me using default settings, 1 em is equal to 16 pt font), and doesn't scale depending on the user's screen resolution.